# Line up image with the bottom edge of the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've done some work with parallax scrolling and resizing my image using javascript, but I cannot figure out how to getting a homepage to line up perfectly with the edge of the window.

The code I have does not line up with the bottom edge of the webpage.

If I do a fix value I can get it to line up; however, depending on whether or not someone has a toolbar it messes up the alignment.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ParallecScrolling</title>
<style type="text/css">
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    #image {
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1
    }
    #content {
        height: 2700px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top:-10px;
        background-color:#4dbbac;
        position: relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
</style>


</head>

<body onresize="myFunction()">

<img id="image" src="IMG.JPG" style="margin:;" />

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    var h = window.outerHeight;
    var yourImg = document.getElementById('image');
        yourImg.height = h;
        yourImg.width = w;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ypos, image;
    function parallex () {
        ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        image = document.getElementById('image');
        image.style.top = ypos * .5 + 'px';
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', parallex);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you looking for background image which covers whole viewport. And do you want it on when fired an event

Comment: I have an image that covers the viewport, and the javascript function I made resizes the image to do just that; however if the user has a toolbar on their browser the function I made still takes the same size the viewport would be without the toolbar. So the image gets pushed down instead of being perfectly on the bottom edge of the screen. I've tried subtracting a fixed value, but then I have a similar problem if I do not have the toolbar, but the websites I posted do not have this problem at all. So I'm trying to figure out how to fix my function to do that. tldr: Yes whole viewport.

Comment: i think you can just use `vh` for height and `%` for width and add a class on event firing. Simple and effective

Comment: Thanks, works almost perfectly, but there is still a slim line of the next slide showing and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Oops, now it works perfectly I forgot I put "margin-top:-10px;" in my conent

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i got your question right but why you dont use bottom property?

```
image.style.bottom = 0;
```